# How to Process Multi Step Forms in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I've made some attempted to use formwizard but there wasn't much documentation about it so I decided to stay with the basic.  I've successfully obtained and display the data from the first form to the second form and added some checkbox next to the data to allow user to choose whether to overwrite or ignore the duplicate data found in the backend process.  The problem I have is the second form doesn't know how retrieve the data of the first form after hitting "Confirm" button.  The form2.html template invalidated the data completely since it called itself again by the form action after submitting the data.  Is there a way to solve this or a better approach to this?

forms.py

```
class NameForm (forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField (required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField (required = False)

class CheckBox (forms.Form):
    overwrite = forms.BooleanField (required = False)
```

views.py

```
def form1 (request):

    NameFormSet = formset_factory (NameForm, formset = BaseNodeFormSet, extra = 2, max_num = 5)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        name_formset = NameFormSet (request.POST, prefix = 'nameform')

        if name_formset.is_valid ():
            data = name_formset.cleaned_data
            request.session ['data'] = data

            context = {'data': data}
            return render (request, 'nameform/form2.html', context)
        else:
            name_formset = NameFormSet (prefix = 'nameform')

     context = {......}

     return render (request, 'nameform/form1.html', context)

def form2 (request):

    request.session ['data'] = data
    CheckBoxFormSet = formset_factory (CheckBox, extra = 2, max_num = 5)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        checkbox_formset = CheckBoxFormSet (request.POST, prefix = 'checkbox')

        if checkbox_formset.is_valid ():
            data = checkbox_formset.cleaned_data

            context = {'data': data}
            return render (request, 'nameform/success.html', context)

        else:
            checkbox_formset = CheckBoxFormSet (prefix = 'checkbox')

     return HttpResponse ('No overwrite data.')
```

form2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'nodeform/style.css' %}" >
    <title>User Information</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>User Information:</h1>
    <form action="form2" method="POST">
    {{ checkbox_formset.management_form }}
    <div id="tablefont">
    <table id="table01">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th class="center">Overwrite</th>
        </tr>
        {% for info in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ info.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ info.last_name }}</td>
            <td class="center"><input id="id_checkbox-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-overwrite" name="checkbox-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-overwrite" type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Confirm">
    <a href="{% url 'form1' %}">
        <button type="button">Cancel</button></a></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find that class based views always make life simpler, and in this case specifically there is the Form Wizard views which use the session or a cookie. Check out the docs; https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

I've just finished writing something very similar to this;

```
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView


class SignupWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'wizard_form.html'
    form_list = [Form1, Form2, Form3]
    model = MyModel

    def get_form_initial(self, step, **kwargs):
        initial = self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
        current_step = self.storage.current_step

        if step or current_step in ['0', 0]:
            initial.update({'field': 'data'})
        elif step or current_step in ['1', 1]:
            initial.update({'field': 'data'})

        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        """
        Supply extra content data for each stage.
        e.g. stage page title
        """
        previous_data = None
        if self.steps.current == self.steps.last:
            previous_data = self.get_all_cleaned_data()

        context = super(SignupWizard, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)
        context.update(
            {
                'review_data': previous_data,
            }
        )
        return context

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        """
        Final page, this is rendered after the post method to the final form.
        """
        form_data_dict = self.get_all_cleaned_data()
        mymodelform = form_list[0].save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect()
```

Essentially there my first form is a `ModelForm` for `MyModel` and I use other standard forms to collect other information. So at the end, grab the first form from the list and save that to create the `MyModel` instance.

Equally as you can see you can grab `self.get_all_cleaned_data()` to get all of the data entered in to the forms through to whole process to handle the data yourself.

The template for something this would be along the lines of;

```
{% extends 'base_wizard.html' %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block form %}
    {% for error in wizard.form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ wizard.form.media }}
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    {% wizard.form.as_p %}
    <div class="controls">
        {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
            <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">
                {% trans "Previous step" %}
            </button>
        {% endif %}
        <button type="submit" name="submit">
            {% trans "Next step" %}
        </button>
    </div>
{% endblock form %}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the django-formtools package has been removed from `django.contrib` in 1.8, but is available as a separate package: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/formtools/#django-contrib-formtools

Comment: I think the problem here is the way I'm rendering the page.  If I were to use formwizard, the result would still be the same.  The data obtained from form1 and sent as variables to form2.  Form2.html action will call form2 method in views to process the data.  From there; whether form2 is submitted or not will "lose" the variables value obtained from form1.  In another word, it doesn't know what {{ info.first_name}} is.  I've tested this by taking out the variable completely and the form processes fine.

Comment: How would I do this with wtf-forms?

Comment: @user805981 I've never used it, but if they're just Django forms, include your wtf-forms in `form_list` & it should work like normal.